# CurrentPage getParameters() is empty the first time I post to a page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, post

I have a VisualForce/APEX page that I am posting to through a form.  I send over a list of contacts as a single string.  When I get to the other page I use the following code to retrieve the post parameters:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('contacts');
```

I am posting the data using the method described in this other [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44863/get-list-of-contacts-from-search-layout) that I asked.  I thought it was working perfectly, but then I noticed that after I logged in and went to the page that first time, the getParameters map would be empty.

I suspect that the page has some kind of internal redirect on the server and is not passing the post data along.  This is likely a security issue to ensure that the user is authorized to view that page the first time that they try and access it.

Does anyone know of a work around for this problem?

Comment: @KeithC Hey, you helped me on my last question about this same setup and was wondering if you have ever run into this issue when you are posting data to a VisualForce page.

Comment: It appears to be necessary to specify the full URL in the post action if you want the parameters map to be populated. This is described in [Re: Get POST data via visualforce page](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000958DIAQ) and used in my blog post [How to pass a large number of selections from a standard list view to a Visualforce page](http://force201.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/how-to-pass-a-large-number-of-selections-from-a-standard-list-view-to-a-visualforce-page/). Have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah you use https://c.__some_org__.visual.force.com/apex/__some_page__. The page won't even load without the full url because they are in completely different domains. I can usually pull out the post data, but on the first time that I load up that page after logging in the post data is empty.  I suspect that when I hit that domain for the first time the server redirects me to an authentication script/page which ends up dropping the post data.

Comment: Yeah I think you are right. Its one thing to carry GET parameters across a login page but a POST that could have large volumes of data is a different thing.